# Giving React component animation on mount

Tags: reactjs, animation, transition, react-transition-group, react-animated

I am trying to make this component move in when mounted but getting

```
Cannot read property 'enter' of undefined
```

Here is a simplified code (I have all the CSS classes ready):

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    transitionIn: false,
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.setState({ transitionIn: true })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CSSTransition
        in={this.state.transitionIn}
        timeout={1000}
        className={'wordTransition'}
      >
        <div>dksjfnsdkjnfj</div>
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/rj5046zxoo

Comment: I was unable to make this work for my code for almost 3 hours, then I saw your codesandbox and I understood that I need to use appear and not entered. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the error you were experiencing is one that you solved in the codesandbox.io link you provided above. I was having this same problem. **Instead of naming the prop that takes a class name to be used as the prefix for the various transition states `classNames` (plural) I was using the more familiar `className` (singular).**

To reiterate: inside the `<CSSTransition>` component, make sure you are using a `classNames` prop and not `className` as you would inside of a react component's html elements.

I feel that the choice on the part of the [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) to use a prop called `classNames` in their component is confusing and should perhaps be reconsidered.